# Geting text from command prompt

Tags: python, command-line, python-3.6, command-prompt

i would like to get text from cmd prompt result.
To exemplify,

```
import os
os.system('net view')
```

The above lines give me below lines

```
Server Name            Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\LAPTOP-5VBGN416
\\RASPBERRYPI          Samba 4.9.5-Debian
The command completed successfully
```

My goal is that get to check whether there is RASPBERRYPI variable. How can i do that?

.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import os
output = os.popen('net view').read()

if 'RASPBERRYPI' in output:
    print("'RASPBERRYPI' was found.")
else:
    print("'RASPBERRYPI' was NOT found.")
```

**Note:** Some people claim that `os.popen()` is deprecated, but according to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71547/is-there-a-problem-with-using-deprecated-os-popen , `os.popen()` is deprecated in Python 2.6, but it is not deprecated in Python 3.x, since in 3.x it is implemented using `subprocess.Popen()` .

---

If you prefer to use the `subprocess` package, you can capture the output this way:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.Popen("net view",   # your command
                          shell=True,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE
         ).communicate()[0]
```

(If you wish, you can change the first two arguments to `.Popen()` to be `["net", "view"]` and `shell=False`, but I'll have the reasons for doing so left up to the reader to research.)  ;-)

Comment: Any particular reason for `Popen("net view", shell=True, ...)` compared to `Popen(["net", "view"], ...)` (defaulting to `shell=False`)?

Comment: @alani, I had to pick something.  But good point -- I added a quick blurb at the end.  (I didn't explain why lest my post snowball in size.)

Comment: thanks a lot. But i am facing an error that **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

Comment: @woz523:  Hmm... Try this:  After you set `output = ...`, insert `print('Type is:', type(output))` and make sure that `Type is: str` is printed out.  If it prints out something different, make sure you're using Python3, and make sure that the line where you set the output is correct (double-check that you didn't leave out any parentheses or arguments).

Comment: @woz523, the **TypeError** that you're getting makes me think that you're passing a `str` into a function that is expecting `bytes`.  The code I posted doesn't expect `bytes`, so I'm thinking the problem is in a section of your code that you didn't post here.  (And without seeing your code, it's hard to tell where the problem is.)  Maybe you can post a small, trimmed-down, and self-working version of your code that shows this problem for us to troubleshoot?